# Function returning empty [object Promise]

Tags: node.js, express

I think this issue has to do with async, but I'm not able to res.send the boolean it just sends as [object Promise] which is empty when I JSON.stringify it on the front end

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var crypto = require("crypto");

var { User } = require("../models/users");

router.get("/", (req, res) => {

  // This logs "[object Promise] Please see here"
  console.log(go().then(function(result) {
    return result
  }) + ' Please see here');

  // This logs true
  go().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  });

  // This returns [object Promise] to front end which is empty
  return res.send((go().then(function(result) {
    return result
  })));

  async function go() {
   doesUserExist = await User.exists({ email: req.query.email });
   return doesUserExist;
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Move `res.send` inside `then`.

Comment: Ah, obviously, I don't know why I didn't think of that thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Because go is an async function, I believe you need to await anytime it is called. Something along these lines:

```
const express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require("mongoose").Types.ObjectId;
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

var crypto = require("crypto");

var { User } = require("../models/users");

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {

  // This logs "[object Promise] Please see here"
  console.log(await go().then(function(result) {
    return result
  }) + ' Please see here');

  // This logs true
  go().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result)
  });

  // This returns [object Promise] to front end which is empty
  return res.send((go().then(function(result) {
    return result
  })));

  async function go() {
   doesUserExist = await User.exists({ email: req.query.email });
   return doesUserExist;
  }

});

module.exports = router;
```